# Center map on a set of coordinates

Tags: glympse

Is it possible to center the map of the Glympse website on a set of coordinates? I'm trying to put it into an iframe for a game with a grid overlay. I want to center the map so that each time you reload the custom website, it is on the right spot(city).

Thanks in advance

Edit: According to Glympse, this is not possible!